# Is there way to directly reference to a pytest fixture from a simple (non test) function?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Is there a way to reference (and call into) a pytest fixture from a simple function that itself is not either a test_* function or also a fixture?

known examples that can use fixtures:

1)

```
def test_mytest( some_cool_pytest_fixture_name, the, rest of, my, args):
    blah
    blah
    some_cool_pytest_fixture_name(args)
    blah

2)
@pytest.fixture()
def my_new_fixture( some_cool_pytest_fixture_name, the, rest of, my, args):
    blah
    blah
    some_cool_pytest_fixture_name(args)
    blah
```

I want to be able to do this:
3)

```
def my_simple_function( the, rest of, my, args):
    blah
    blah
    outright.reference.this.pytest.fixture.some_cool_pytest_fixture_name(args)
    blah
```

**NOTE:**

```
from pytest import record_xml_property as property_handler
 ** E ImportError: cannot import name record_xml_property**
```

^^^ This in on a system which does have the **record_xml_property**

My desire is to be able to do something like this:

```
try: 
     from pytest import record_xml_property as property_handler 
 except: 
     @pytest.fixture() 
     def property_handler(mykey, myval): 
         print('{0}={1}'.format(mykey,myval)
```

^^^ If the above can succeed, then I can always depend on **property_handler** being there for me as a fixture.

Comment: Your test code should import your application code. Importing test code from your application should never be necessary. The Pytest test runner does a bunch of magic such as [assertion rewriting](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#advanced-assertion-introspection) and monkey patching. Pytest fixtures are not designed to work outside of pytest.

Comment: If you need some shared functionality, just import it into your tests and wrap it in a `pytest.fixture` there.

Answer (score 1):

When you use pytest's built in fixture handling, you don't have to worry about how to manage it's availability and memory.

So when you aren't using pytest, you can just import it as a normal function.

```
from path.to.cool.pytest.fixture import some_cool_pytest_fixture_name

def my_simple_function(the, rest of, my, args):
    some_cool_pytest_fixture_name(args)
```

---

**Edit**

In response to Ken's note, I spent some time trying to access the list of available fixtures defined in pytest.  I've come up with two ways to access the list, but haven't pushed it far enough to get the list in a python list format, only the console output.

From the command line, you can run `pytest --fixtures` to list all fixtures available.  To do the same thing from a python script, you can run this code

```
import pytest
from _pytest import python
from _pytest import config
configs = config._prepareconfig()
python.showfixtures(configs)
```

I think you could access the list if you dig into the pytest Session object and look into its `_fixturemanager` attribute, but I couldn't figure out a way to create these like the function `showfixtures` above does.

Comment: `from pytest import record_xml_property as property_handler`
** E  ImportError: cannot import name record_xml_property**
 
 ^^^  This in on a system which does have the record_xml_property
 
 My desire is to be able to do something like this.
     
    `try:
        from pytest import record_xml_property as property_handler
    except:
        @pytest.fixture()
        def property_handler(mykey, myval):
            print('{0}={1}'.format(mykey,myval)`
 
 ^^^  If the above can succeed, then I can always depend on **property_handler** being there for me as a fixture.

Comment: @sauln, see my added NOTE to my original question.

Comment: @KenB ahh okay. I didn't realize you wanted to get predefined.  Give me a second and I'll try to address your note.

Comment: @KenB, I spent some time digging into pytest and haven't found any graceful way to solve the problem.  You can list all of the fixtures using `pytest --fixtures`.  You could probably capture and parse this output to figure out what you needed, but just accessing the list directly from python evades me.  I'll put my work in progress in the answer to the question.

Comment: Just a note for people finding this answer, I believe that calling a fixture directly is now depricated: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly (I'm searching for a solution to the same use case, haven't found one yet)